# My professor's example apparently works, but when I do the same thing, it doesn't work for me?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using I believe the latest version of Java and Eclipse.

Her instructions say: "Create a new class. A field is a String message "Taking COMP 110". A method printing is used to print a message string. "This method is from an object." Then it says "give an explanation of what is happening. Why the same result?""

And the example she gave is:

```
public class myOwnObject {
String anylegalname = "taking COMP 110";
public void printing(){
System.out.println(anylegalname);
}
}
```

But I tried this and... it doesn't work. Eclipse tells me it needs public static void main(String [] args)... what gives?

Comment: Yes eclipse is clear in error, you need to have main method to run. What is doubt there?

Comment: That's exacly what you need to do; add a main method, so you program can start from it. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=public+static+void+main(String+%5B%5D+args)&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=fuHaV-fxBMLK8gf1pZKAAg

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse tells me it needs public static void main(String [] args)... what gives?

You're trying to run the class as the main class of a program, the Eclipse equivalent of the standard `java myOwnObject` command-line.

When you do that, the main class must have a static `main` method with the signature Eclipse is showing you, because that's the entry point of the program.

Only classes you want to run as the main class need this. So code that's run a different way (by a web server, by some other kind of container) doesn't need a `main`. Only the main class of a standalone program run via  the `java` tool (or equivalent tool integrated into your IDE).

---

Your professor should have explained what `main` was for fairly early on. You should probably read some basic Java tutorials if she didn't, rather than relying on her.

She should also have told you that *overwhelmingly*, the convention in Java is for a class name to start with an uppercase character. So `MyOwnObject` (or better, `MyOwnClass`) rather than `myOwnObject`.

Answer (score 0):

One class in your .java file must have a `public static void main(String[] args)`.
This is the entry point for your application.

So you wrote a class, but you would need to add the above and instantiate an instance of your class inside your main.

Here's a tutorial that explains it a bit more:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, updated, thanks